# linux bash waiting for multiple files to exist

Tags: linux, bash, triggers, wait

I have a linux bash script that needs 3 files to be created before it can start. I have found a script from 'a_programmer' from a forum (Thanks!) - but can't make it work.

a first file 'TESTING12' is created at the start ; but the second file 'TESTING34' should only be created when f1, f2, f3 exist.
There are errors in my attempt (even the echo) as it does not work.

any hints would be appreciated.

bonus question: can I wait for files that exist in another directory; like waiting for ../dir1/f1 ../dir2/f2 and ../dir3/f3

```
touch TESTING12

TMP_TRG_FILE = 'f1 f2 f3'
echo $TMP_TRG_FILE
while read trigger_file
do
   while [[ ! -e $trigger_file ]]
   do
      print "Waiting for trigger file: $trigger_file"
      sleep 5
   done
done < $TMP_TRG_FILE

touch TESTING34
```

Comment: Why don't you just [ -e f1 ] && [ -e f2 ] && [ -e f3 ]?  If you don't want to busy wait check out one of the inotify solutions (entr, inotify-hookable, inotify-tools, iwatch etc).

Comment: Hi Allan - thanks for the reply. as you have gathered I'm new to bash script. Could you show me how to use [ -e f1 ] && [ -e f2 ] && [ -e f3 ] you mentionned above? - is that in my while loop?

Comment: TMP_TRG_FILE contains the string `f1 f2 f3` and your loop is reading from this file. Do you have a file named `f1 f2 f3`? Otherwise you should get an error message here. The `echo` should work, however (and output _f1 f2 f3_ ).

Comment: BTW, is it a good idea to hard-code the name and number of the files you are waiting for? Intuitively I think the script would benefit from being written so that it can wait for the existence of any arbitrary set of files (which could be passed, for instance, on the command line).

Comment: Hiya user1934428! thanks for taking the time. as the code is written above, it does not work as i wish it would: f1 f2 f3 don't exist yet, but the waiting loop does not wait and file 'TESTING34' is created (it should wait until f1 f2 and f3 are created to exit the loop and create 'TESTING34'. The solution provided by Allan Wind works though. Agree with you that hard-coding is prob not the best in the long term but my knowledge of scripting being limited, I don't want to spend more time on it. I really appreciate your input nonetheless! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with something like this (assuming f1, f2 and f3 are the 3 files you are waiting for):

```
while [ ! -e f1 ] || [ ! -e f2 ] || [ ! -e f3 ]
do
   echo "Waiting for files..."
   sleep 5
done
echo "ready to rock'in roll"
```

Comment: many many thanks Allan for the help! really appreciated!

Comment: @MrT. Any time.  "First name: Mister; middle name: period; last name T."